# Angular JS - How to retrieve username from BASIC authentication

Tags: angularjs, basic-authentication

We have implemented a Angular web app. The app is authenticated using BASIC authentication which was done using Spring Boot.

The basic authentication works fine. But how can I retrieve the user name from the HTTP Request header using Angular.

We need the usename later to pass in every DB Stored procedure calls.

The username is available in the HTTP header as below.

**Authorization:Basic amF5YXJhbWFuajpQYXNzd29yZDAx**

Comment: can you try atob(username)

Answer (score 0):

The authorization format is: `user:password` written in base64.

You can get the user easily by decoding the base64 authorization text.

Comment: Thanks. Yes we can decode easily, but not sure how to retrieve these values within Angular.